# Contador y agregado de Usuario

Tags: python, django

estoy desarrollando un sistema en Django, y para ello uso el "admin" del mismo que me parece muy ágil. He realizado la mayoria de lo que necesitaba, pero tengo una dificultad para guardar 2 campos ('Usuario' y 'Número de muestra').
El primero lo pude resolver pero el segundo no he logrado aplicar lo que pensé.

Tengo el modelo 'Muestra':

```
class Muestra(models.Model):
TIPO_PRES = (
    ('0', 'APS'),
    ('1', 'CONVENIO'),
    ('2', 'ARANCELADO'),
    ('3', 'CALIDAD'),
    ('4', 'CONTROL INTERNO'),
)
ENTRADA = (
    ('0', 'DECOMISO'),
    ('1', 'CONTROL'),
    ('2', 'INTERVENCION'),
    ('3', 'DENUNCIA'),
    ('4', 'LICITACION'),
    ('5', 'INTOXICACION'),
    ('6', 'MUESTREO PROGRAMADO'),
)
departamento = models.ForeignKey(Departamento, models.DO_NOTHING)
numero = models.PositiveIntegerField()
tipo_prestacion = models.CharField(max_length=45, choices=TIPO_PRES)
entrada = models.CharField(max_length=45, choices=ENTRADA)
nro_cert_cadena_custodia = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
matriz = models.ForeignKey(Matriz, models.DO_NOTHING)
tipomuestra = ChainedForeignKey(
        Tipomuestra,
        chained_field="matriz",
        chained_model_field="matriz")
muestra = models.CharField(max_length=255)
identificacion = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
solicitante = models.CharField(max_length=45)
remitente = models.ForeignKey(Remitente, models.DO_NOTHING)
fecha_entrada = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
realizo_muestreo = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
lugar_extraccion = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
fecha_extraccion = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
hora_extraccion = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
provincia = models.ForeignKey(Provincia, models.DO_NOTHING)
localidad = ChainedForeignKey(
        Localidad,
        chained_field="provincia",
        chained_model_field="provincia")
conservacion = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
cloro_residual = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
elaborado_por = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
domicilio = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
marca = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
tipo_envase = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
cantidad = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
peso_volumen = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
fecha_elaborado = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
fecha_vencimiento = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
registro_establecimiento = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
registro_producto = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
lote = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
partida = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
destino = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
microbiologia = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
quimica = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
cromatografia = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
ensayo_biologico = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
aceptada = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
criterio_rechazo = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
fecha_recepcion_analista = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
fecha_inicio_analisis = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
fecha_fin_analisis = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
observaciones = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
condicion = models.CharField(max_length=45)
cargada = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
reviso = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
revisada = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
fecha_salida = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
remitir = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
codigo_barra = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
auth_user = models.ForeignKey(AuthUser, models.DO_NOTHING)
ticket_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
ensayo = ChainedManyToManyField(
    Ensayo,
    horizontal=True,
    verbose_name='ensayo',
    chained_field="matriz",
    chained_model_field="matriz")


class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'muestra'

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.matriz) + ' - ' + str(self.tipomuestra) + ' - ' + str(self.numero)
aceptada.boolean = True
```

En el admin.py:

```
class MuestraAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
menu_title = "DSA menu"
menu_group = "Muestras"
list_display = ('numero', 'tipomuestra', 'muestra', 'remitente', 'lugar_extraccion', 'aceptada')
search_fields = ('numero', 'muestra', 'lugar_extraccion', 'remitente')
actions = [aceptar, rechazar]
fields = ('numero', 'departamento', 'tipo_prestacion', 'entrada', 'matriz', 'tipomuestra', 'muestra', 'solicitante', 'remitente', 'lugar_extraccion', 'provincia', 'localidad', 'condicion', 'ensayo')
autocomplete_fields = ['remitente']
readonly_fields = ('numero',)
exclude = ('auth_user',)
def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
    return False
def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    form = super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
    form.base_fields['departamento'].widget.can_change_related = False
    form.base_fields['departamento'].widget.can_add_related = False
    form.base_fields['departamento'].widget.can_delete_related = False
    form.base_fields['matriz'].widget.can_change_related = False
    form.base_fields['matriz'].widget.can_add_related = False
    form.base_fields['matriz'].widget.can_delete_related = False
    form.base_fields['remitente'].widget.can_change_related = False
    form.base_fields['remitente'].widget.can_add_related = False
    form.base_fields['remitente'].widget.can_delete_related = False
    form.base_fields['localidad'].widget.can_change_related = False
    form.base_fields['localidad'].widget.can_add_related = False
    form.base_fields['localidad'].widget.can_delete_related = False
    form.base_fields['tipomuestra'].widget.can_change_related = False
    form.base_fields['tipomuestra'].widget.can_add_related = False
    form.base_fields['tipomuestra'].widget.can_delete_related = False
    return form

def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    obj.auth_user_id = request.user.id
    ultimo_ano = Muestra.objects.latest('fecha_entrada__year')
    ultimo_numero = Muestra.objects.latest('numero')
    ano_actual = date.today().year
    if not obj.pk:
        if ano_actual == ultimo_ano:
            obj.numero == ultimo_numero+1
        else:
            obj.numero == 1
    super(MuestraAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Cuando probé el usuario solo funciona, pero cuando agrego lo del "numero" me arroja el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intuyo que estoy pasando dos objetos, pero no se como debería hacerlo, o alomejor es otro el problema.
Realmente agradecería una ayuda con ésto.
Desde ya muchas gracias, saludos

Comment: Tienes obj.numero == ultimo_numero+1 en vez de obj.numero = ultimo_numero+1

Comment: Y también obj.numero == 1 en vez de obj.numero = 1 en el else

Comment: Muchas gracias! Ahora no me arroja error, pero tengo un problema con la comparación de los años ya que siempre pasa al else. Seguiré intentando otra forma de hacer esa comparación. Gracias